# How can I stop and delete a docker container launched with restart always option?

Tags: docker, puppet

I run some containers with the option *--restart always*.

It works good, so good, that I have now difficulties to stop these containers now :)

I tried :

```
sudo docker stop container && sudo docker rm -f container
```

But the container still restarts.

The [docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/cli/#restart-policies) explains the restart policies, but I didn't find anything to resolve this issue.

Comment: Have you tried `docker kill`?

Comment: @Dijkgraaf thaks! it's only one command that helped me!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Many thanks for those who takes time to respond.

If you use docker directly, Bryan is right `sudo docker rm -f container` is enough.

My problem was mainly that I use puppet to deploy docker images and run containers. I use [this module](https://docs.docker.com/articles/host_integration/) and it creates entries in /etc/init for the upstart process manager.

I think, my problem whas that, some kind of incompatibilities between the process manager and docker.

In this situation, to halt a container, simply `sudo stop docker-container`.

More informations on managing docker container run can be found on [the docker website](https://docs.docker.com/articles/host_integration/)

Comment: With the latest version of [the docker puppet module](https://github.com/garethr/garethr-docker) containters script have been moved to /etc/init.d, so you need to :
`sudo /etc/init.d/docker-container-name stop`

Comment: you also can use:  **docker update --restart=no <container_name>** check [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37599128/docker-how-do-you-disable-auto-restart-on-a-container/37600885#37600885)

Answer (score 14):

Just

```
sudo docker rm -f container
```

will kill the process if it is running and remove the container, in one step.

That said, I couldn't replicate the symptoms you described.  If I run with `--restart=always`, `docker stop` will stop the process and it remains stopped.

I am using Docker version 1.3.1.

Comment: Ignore me. The problem was the container had been started by a service, and so always restarted until I killed the service itself.

Answer (score 11):

`docker update --restart=no <container>`