# docker - how do you disable auto-restart on a container?

Tags: docker

I can enable auto-restart with `--restart=always`, but after I stop the container, how do I turn off that attribute?

I normally run a webserver and typically map port 80:

```
docker run -d --restart=always -p 80:80 -i -t myuser/myproj /bin/bash
```

But there are times when I want to run a newer version of my image, but I want to keep the old container around.  The problem is that if there are multiple containers with `--restart=always`, only one of them (random?) starts because they're all contending for port 80 on the host.

Answer (score 563, accepted):

You can use the `--restart=unless-stopped` option, as @Shibashis mentioned, or update the restart policy (this requires docker 1.11 or newer);

See the [documentation for `docker update`](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/v1.11.2/docs/reference/commandline/update.md#update-a-containers-restart-policy) and [Docker restart policies](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#restart-policies---restart).

```
docker update --restart=no my-container
```

that updates the restart-policy for an existing container (`my-container`)

Comment: Use `docker update --restart=no $(docker ps -a -q)` to update all your containers :-)

Comment: If docker is stopped and won't start because of some containers autostarting and causing problems, you can do this with docker off: `sed s@always@no@ -i /var/lib/docker/containers/*/hostconfig.json`

Answer (score 111):

Use the below to disable ALL auto-restarting (daemon) containers.

```
docker update --restart=no $(docker ps -a -q)
```

Use the following to disable restart a SINGLE container.

```
docker update --restart=no the-container-you-want-to-disable-restart
```

**Rationale**:

Docker provides restart policies to control whether your containers start automatically when they exit, or when Docker restarts.  This is often very useful when Docker is running a key service.

**Notes**

If you are using docker-compose this might be useful to know.

> restart no is the default restart policy, and it does not restart a
> container under any circumstance. When always is specified, the
> container always restarts. The on-failure policy restarts a container
> if the exit code indicates an on-failure error.

```
restart: "no"
restart: always
restart: on-failure
restart: unless-stopped

restart: always
```

Answer (score 41):

You can start your container with `--restart=unless-stopped`.

Answer (score 37):

If you have a swarm restarting the containers, the swarm will restart any containers you stop or rm, irrespective of the restart option.  That's a feature, not a bug.

Make sure you are not running a service you forgot about:

```
docker service ls
```

Then, you can stop the service

```
docker service rm <service id discovered with previous command>
```

Comment: `ls` results in error `Error response from daemon: This node is not a swarm manager. Use "docker swarm init" or "docker swarm join" to connect this node to swarm and try again.`

Comment: That gave me a right hint to stop a `mongo-demo_mongo-express` container, which was started by `docker stack deploy ...`  (https://hub.docker.com/_/mongo).

Answer (score 4):

Not a response to this question but to [How to prevent docker from starting a container automatically on system startup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40513545/how-to-prevent-docker-from-starting-a-container-automatically-on-system-startup), which has been marked as a duplicate of this question.

If your container is started with `restart=on-failure` and has a faulty command that exits with a non-zero exit code when you stop the container with `docker stop`, it shows some weird behaviour: After stopping the container with `docker stop`, the container is stopped, but after restarting the docker daemon (or the system), it is started automatically again. To fix this, either fix the command of the container or use `no` or `unless-stopped` as the restart policy.

Answer (score 3):

### To change the restart policy of all docker containers...

#### Identify the docker containers that will start on boot

This shell script will identify any docker containers that have a restart policy other than "no".

##### As the root user

```sh
CONTAINERS=$(for f in  /var/lib/docker/containers/*/hostconfig.json ; 
do 
container=`echo $f | rev | cut -d '/' -f 2| rev`
jq \
 --arg container "$container" \
 --arg file "$f" '{"RestartPolicy":.RestartPolicy.Name, 'file':$file, 'container':$container} | select(.RestartPolicy != "no")' "$f" | \
  jq .container -r | tr '\n' ' '
done)
```

##### or as NON-root...

```sh
CONTAINERS=$(for f in  $(sudo sh -c "ls /var/lib/docker/containers/*/hostconfig.json"); 
do 
container=`echo $f | rev | cut -d '/' -f 2| rev`
sudo jq \
  --arg container "$container" \
  --arg file "$f" '{"RestartPolicy":.RestartPolicy.Name, 'file':$file, 'container':$container} | select(.RestartPolicy != "no")' "$f" | \
  jq .container -r | tr '\n' ' '
done)
```

##### (optionally) View the list of selected containers

```sh
echo $CONTAINERS
```

##### Sset all of the containers to "no" at once.

```sh
docker update --restart=no $CONTAINERS
```

Comment: If you do not have jq installed you can use this to identify the containers which have the RestartPolicy set to "always": `sudo sh -c 'grep -l "RestartPolicy\":{\"Name\":\"always\"" /var/lib/docker/containers/*/hostconfig.json'`

Answer (score 2):

docker update --restart=yes/no <container-name/containerId>

Comment: `--restart=yes` is not [documented](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#restart-policies---restart). The rest simply duplicates the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37600885/711006).

Answer (score 2):

Update only actively running containers:

```
docker update --restart=no $(docker ps -q)
```