# How to prevent docker from starting a container automatically on system startup?

Tags: docker, startup

Docker starts a container on every system startup (debian) but I didn't create a service to do so. How can I prevent docker from doing that?

Comment: I disagree with this being marked as a duplicate. The other question asks about how to disable restarting for a container that has been intentionally configured to restart using `restart=always`, while this question is about how to disable restarting for a conainer that has been **unintentionally** configured to restart. `restart=always` is only one possible reason why a container is restarting.

Comment: In fact, I would like to give an answer for another scenario where a container configured with `restart=on-failure` unintentionally restarts on every system boot. That answer would fit here, but it doesn't fit to the other question.

Comment: I’ve posted a response to this question on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65894195/242365).

Comment: See docs for [start containers automatically](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/) it works for `docker run` and `docker update`

Comment: There's another interpretation of this question which is, how do I prevent docker from restarting containers on boot even if the container has `restart=always`. [I've made a new question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75230964/how-to-prevent-all-docker-containers-from-automatically-restarting-on-boot) to answer this variant.

Answer (score 589, accepted):

Docker will autostart any container with a `RestartPolicy` of `'always'` when the docker service initially starts. You won't find any evidence of this within cron or any other normal system startup scripts; you'll have to dig into the container configuration to find it.

`docker inspect my-container`
(Look for `RestartPolicy` in the output)

I've mostly had this situation occur when a container was created with `--restart always`, and the situation later changed such that I no longer wanted this to happen.

After docker 1.11, this is easy to fix

`docker update --restart=no my-container`

Original answer is here: [docker - how do you disable auto-restart on a container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37599128/docker-how-do-you-disable-auto-restart-on-a-container)

Comment: great answer. In order to quickly find the RestartPolicy config, you can use `docker inspect my-container | grep -A 3 RestartPolicy`. The `-A n` grep option shows n lines after the match.

Comment: That did the trick, however there wasn't a "RestartPolicy" in my output (used grep). Worked nonetheless. Thanks!

Comment: Did you check that you don't have a stack created ?

e.g. I had executed once the following code and forget... 

 docker stack deploy --compose-file stack.yml vossibility

This makes that automatically containers are created and started everytime those containers defined on compose file stop.

I was reading more about it on ofitial documentation and the esasy one was remove the stack.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/stack/

Answer (score 33):

The info is in `/var/lib/docker/containers/<hash>/hostconfig.json`
(having root permissions)

check for `RestartPolicy.Name = "always"` in any of those files.

Comment: for me it was in /var/lib/docker/containers/ with an s. Also needed to use sudo

Comment: checking only does not prevent docker container from starting automatically on system restart.

Comment: You must leave the value empty to disable the policy.

Answer (score -5):

1. You can also take a look in System->Preferences->Startup Applications. (Search startup application app)
2. use this command : 'Crontab -l' (check any cronjob is set or not)
3. grep docker in /etc/init.d and if you find you can remove from there with sudo permission ( Make sure you dont change other files or anything else, do it on your risk )
4. sudo docker run --restart=no redis (replace redis with your container name)

Let me know if you still find any problem.

Comment: 1. Its okay if docker starts on system startup, so I don't think that a specific container would appear here (anyway: I am using awesome wm so I dont have that menu)
2. Dont have any cronjobs listed
3. No service in /etc/init.d

Anymore ideas?

Comment: sudo docker run --restart=no redis

Comment: replace redis with your container name

Comment: Got it being removed with removing the container (therefore removed all with: docker rm `docker ps --no-trunc -aq`). But I sure accept your answer because there are few notes which could help. Thanks!

Answer (score -8):

Launch Docker if not running.
Click the Docker icon in the menu bar.
Select Preferences... (or press Cmd-comma).
Deselect 'Start Docker when you log in' on the General tab.
Close the Preferences window.
Quit Docker (Cmd-Q or use the menu).

Comment: Adrian, this question is not asking how to stop docker from running on startup, but how to avoid containers starting automatically when you start docker.