# How to prevent all docker containers from automatically restarting on boot?

Tags: linux, docker, containers, systemd

I often deploy docker containers for development on my laptop and then shutdown my computer forgetting to shut down the docker containers. To my surprise, many reboots later these containers are still running.

How can I change this behavior so that any docker container, regardless of whether the container has a restart policy attached to it, will not be restarted on the next boot?

I am running Linux and docker is running via systemd.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by creating a oneshot systemd service that depends on docker (setting the order via `After=`) and then run a script on shutdown to stop and remove all containers.

Systemd service (ie. place in `/etc/systemd/system/shutdown-docker-containers.service`):

```ini
[Unit]
Description="Service to prevent restarting docker containers on next bootup"
After=docker.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=true
ExecStop=/opt/docker-container-shutdown.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=docker.service
```

Script for removing docker containers (`/opt/docker-container-shutdown.sh`):

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

containers=$(docker ps -q)

[ -z "$containers" ] || {
    docker stop $containers
    docker rm $containers
}
```

Finally, make the script executable, reload systemd, and enable the service:

```bash
sudo chmod +x /opt/docker-container-shutdown.sh
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable --now /etc/systemd/system/shutdown-docker-containers.service
```

Comment: I can't believe it must be this complicated. Is there no explicit configurable that can be used to tell docker, "Hey, docker, when I say shutdown I mean containers too, and for good"?