# How to stop a dangling docker-compose up

Tags: docker, docker-compose

sometime ago I ran a `docker-compose up` in some directory. Everytime I reboot my computer docker restarts these processes but I don't want this anymore. Even if I manually stop the containers with docker stop they are restarted again after a restart.

Sadly, I think I removed the directory where I executed `docker-compose up` and `down` won't work because of this.
Any idea where I can find a solution? I was also not sure what to google..

Regards,

@edit no duplicate since it is not directly connected to the restart policy of docker.

Comment: Delete the containers if you don't need them anymore.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [docker - how do you disable auto-restart on a container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37599128/docker-how-do-you-disable-auto-restart-on-a-container)

Comment: @tkausl yes that worked. How easy... sometimes you don't see the easiest solution:-d  thanks for the prompt reply.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to delete the containers.

Credits to  @tkausl.

Comment: Seems that @tkausl should be author of this answer and with this @ this looks like reply to some comment at first moment