# Zombie docker container that can't be killed

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I use docker-compose to create a bunch of containers and link them together. For some of the container definitions, I might have `restart: always` as the restart policy.

Now I have a postgres container that respawns back to life if stopped.

```
$docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
a8bb2b781630        postgres:latest     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   About an hour ago   Up About an hour    5432/tcp            dcat_postgres.1.z3pyl24kiq2n4clt0ua77nfx5
docker stop a8bb2b781630
a8bb2b781630
$ docker rm -f a8bb2b781630
a8bb2b781630
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
93fa7b72c2ca        postgres:latest     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   12 seconds ago      Up 4 seconds        5432/tcp            dcat_postgres.1.oucuo5zg3y9ws3p7jvlfztflb
```

Using `docker-compose down` in the dir that started the service doesn't work either.

```
$ docker-compose down
Removing dcat_postgres_1 ... done
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
7ee7fb0e98cd        postgres:latest     "docker-entrypoint.s…"   13 seconds ago      Up 5 seconds        5432/tcp            dcat_postgres.1.jhv1q6vns1avakqjxdusmbb78
```

How can I kill a container and keep it from coming back to life?

**EDIT**: The container respawns even after restarting the Docker service.

Docker - 18.06.1-ce-mac73 (26764)

macOS High-Sierra, (10.13.6)

Comment: If the person downvoted could tell me what's wrong with the question maybe I could improve it.

Comment: Your containers are different in a couple of interesting ways (the hex ID, the generated name) and I don't think a Docker restart policy is recreating them.  I don't think there's enough information here to guess what is actually doing it.

Comment: Have you tried `docker rm -f <container>`?

Comment: @DavidMaze, the generated name sure looks weird. But I thought the hex ID is normal, no? What info can I get that you think would be helpful?

Comment: @AlexKarshin, yes, you can see it in the code snippet above.

Comment: No, I don't. All you do is `docker rm`, not `docker rm -f`

Comment: @AlexKarshin, sorry, I missed the `-f` will try it ASAC.

Comment: More specifically the name `dcat_postgres.1.z3pyl24kiq2n4clt0ua77nfx5` isn’t a format that Docker wil generate by default, and when the container is recreated, the container name is different.  That’s why I think it isn’t Docker or your container doing the restart on its own, something else is noticing the container is gone and creating a new one.

Comment: @AlexKarshin, I tried it, got the same result.

Comment: @DavidMaze, docker-compose tends create it's own names but usually it's just `(directory of the docker-compose.yml)_(container name defined in docker-compose.yml)_(integer)`, but this doesn't fit that description. FYI, it restarts even after restarting the docker service.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I figured it out. Turns out it was related to docker swarm. I had experimented with it at some point without fully understanding what it is and what it does and apparently it just stayed there.

All I had to do was:

```
docker swarm leave --force
```

and it worked like a head-shot to an actual zombie.

Comment: This makes sense.  Joining a swarm cluster allows the master nodes to control the docker daemon on the host machine.  Glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 11):

Can you try an option like [`moby/moby` issue 10032](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/10032#issuecomment-310023443):

```
docker stop $(docker ps -a -q) &
docker update --restart=no $(docker ps -a -q) &
systemctl restart docker
```

(this assume here you have only one running container: the one you cannot prevent to start)

A `docker rm -f` should be enough though, unless you are [using docker with a provision tool like Puppet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27297279/6309).

As it turned out, another process (other than docker itself) was responsible for the container to restart (here [`docker swarm`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/))

---

Update 2020/2021: [For multiple containers](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/10032#issuecomment-662515567), possibly without having to restart the docker daemon

```
docker ps -a --format="{{.ID}}" | \
 xargs docker update --restart=no | \
 xargs docker stop
```

Check if you need, as in the issue, remove the images as well ( `| xargs docker rmi $(docker images -qa) --force`)

Comment: There is no equivalent of `systemctl restart docker` in macOS so I had to manually restart the docker engine from the GUI. But the zombie container came back to life again.

Comment: @yam That means you have another process/provision tool (or setting, like a .bashrc) which trigger the restart of the container.

Comment: turns out it was `docker swarm` that I had experimented with (see my answer above). Thanks for taking the time to answer though.

Comment: @yam so I was right: another process was responsible for the container to restart?

Comment: Yes, it was another process but not a 3rd party app.

Comment: @yam same general idea though.

Comment: *this assume here you have only one running container* - and what if you have more?

Comment: @SimonForsberg You would need to filter your `docker ps`on the container name: `docker ps -f name='^<Container-name>$`, if you want to target one specific container.

Comment: @VonC Do I still have to perform the `systemctl restart docker` ? Won't that terminate all my other (perfectly healthy) docker containers?

Comment: @SimonForsberg Apparently not: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/10032#issuecomment-662515567

Comment: @VonC I went for a full reboot. Not the ideal solution, but my patience with Docker ran out.

Comment: @SimonForsberg I understand, that would work too ;)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue when playing around with an Ansible deployment of Matrix. I just could not kill it until I did this

```bash
CONTAINERS=$(echo $(sudo docker ps | grep matrix | awk '{print $1;}'))
sudo docker container stop $CONTAINERS && sudo docker system prune -a
```

Here' I'm grepping on `matrix` but you could use as you like. It's really the prune right after the stop that does the zombie removal.